# Star flare in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Continuing my star flare question. I am now teaching myself Eevee and Blender 2.8. I'd like to add the star flare as seen in this screenshot to one of my sets. I want to set it to a stage light bulb. Anyone have any suggestions?

*EDIT* compositing seems to work but not quite as I expect. Index OB and Index MA are gone and I'm trying to assign the flare with streaks to one object or one material. Suggestions?

*EDIT 2* I am so close with this! But it's hitting the neon lights, which I don't want it to do. Just the stage lights in the back. By the way, super thankful for your help! Any suggestions on separating? The neon is a different hue of blue, but it seems to hit all blues.

[image]

Comment: I think your only option will be to use the compositor to add the flare - Eevee does include Bloom settings but this is non-directional.

Comment: I have a flare node already made, but it seems like I'm having issues making it appear.

Comment: @Dustin.james instead of using comments, [edit] your question and add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer of your question via the green mark on the top left corner of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, values rendered fromm Eevee don't seem to be taken into acount when compositing. I don't know if it's a bug. But here's a work around :

- Set a color for the objects you want to add streaks on. Make sure you don't use that color anywhere else in your scene. I used a full red (rgb 1:0:0)
- In the compositor, we will use a Chroma Key node do create a mask out of that color. Play with the cutoff & acceptance to really isolate your lights
- With Alpha Over node, we will take the original render and use the new mask as factor to put our lights on black background
- Let's add a glare node. The mix value must be set to 0
- Mix the glare result to the original render with 0.5 factor

[image: demo picture]

It's really not the best solution but hopefully, all the render passes will be back at some point.